# Kibana Count Field

Tags: count, field, kibana

I'm having a problem with Kibana.

I have a report that counts when an user clicks on a link in my page.

The problem is that the number is without separations:

"1000000" and its hard to read.

Is posible to that number comes separated with "." ? : "1.000.000" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, currently it's not possible, but there is an open [feature request](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1543#issuecomment-67421300) in regards.